# Possible return values for (new Date()).toDateString() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

The return value for `(new Date()).toDateString()` is `"Mon Oct 08 2012"`. However I can't find ANY documentation anywhere for what the abbreviations for the rest of the days of the week and months are. Are they all just 3 character abbreviations? I'm trying to write a regex.

+1million points for someone who can find the documentation, or even the source code?

Comment: ECMA-262 says the return value is implementation dependent, so it is not documented there. You may find browser vendor specific documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three letter abbreviations with the first letter upper case.

- Months: Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec
- Days: Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat

However, you may want to look into Date.Parse() instead of using a regular expression to parse the date string, depending on what you're doing anyway.

EDIT: Beware that that Date.Parse() is fairly browser dependent. Check out [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse)

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! Date.parse() even simplifies things.

Comment: Do not use `Date.parse()`, even though [ES5](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2) defines an [ISO8601–like format](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), the OP isn't in that format and it's not consistent in all browsers. **Manually parse date strings**.

Comment: Bah, only in web frontend programming does one have to reinvent the wheel instead of using existing API functions...

Answer (score 1):

It's just the standard English language abbreviation for days and months. Just the first 3 letters and the first one capitalized.

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString):

> Date instances refer to a specific point in time. Calling toString
>   will return the date formatted in a **human readable form in American
>   English**

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard to find:

W3Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_todatestring.asp

Mozilla Developer Network: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString)

Microsoft Developer Network: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/microsoft.jscript.dateprototype.todatestring%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

As you can see, all of them converge, its the week day, the month name, both with 3 characters, day of month and full year.

Answer (score 1):

The [specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.2) does not define the output of the string:

> The contents of the String are implementation-dependent, but are intended to represent the "date" portion of the Date in the current time zone in a convenient, human-readable form.

This might change in the future, but for now, each browser/environment can produce a different output.